# How does Linux kernel know what CPU peripheral registers it has?

Tags: linux, driver

I have spent some time on linux driver, and this question always confused me: how does kernel know where, and what, on-chip peripheral register the CPU it is running on has?

For example, I am using a Cyclone V SOC with an ARM A9 inside. It has 4 I2C controller, and the base address of each is 0xFFC04000, 0xFFC05000, 0xFFC06000, and 0xFFC07000. Upon each base address, there is an Control Register at offset 0x0, a Data Register at offset 0Xx10, and so on.

Whatever data structure I2C driver model has, all those operations from driver C code should finally be reflected to the operations to those registers, right? If you want to get your I2C RX data, finally there should be some operations fetching at the Data Register, which is the only place the data could be on whole CPU. **How does kernel know what registers the CPU's peripheral has and where are them, and the functionality of each of them?**

I know device tree provide some information to kernel on hardware resources, but typically it is like:

```
i2c0: i2c@ffc04000 
{
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            compatible = "snps,designware-i2c";
            reg = <0xffc04000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0 158 4>;
            clocks = <&l4_sp_clk>;
            status = "okay";
};
```

**It only tells CPU the base address of first I2C controller is at 0xffc04000, and the length of its register section is 0x1000. Nothing else.** The CPU still doesn't know what is inside this 0x1000 section, what registers are there, what purpose, what address offset.

I know mmap/ioremap can map physical address to virtual address, but this is not what I am asking for.

Thanks so much~~

Comment: `compatible = "snps,designware-i2c";` this line tells the kernel what kind if driver it should use, and that driver knows everything. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-designware-platdrv.c

Comment: unix.SE is a better place to ask questions about the design of Unix.

Comment: @user3528438 you are right. I found the address offset information at drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-designware-core.c Thanks so much~~